# Explore a WPF TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to get the content of a graphical elements present in a WPF TabItem.

Consider the following code for the window :

```
<TabItem x:Name="TheItem" Header="Form">
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
        <TextBox x:Name="txtContent" Text="Hello I'm some content !" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtOther" Text="Some other content" />
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

I've looked up the [TabItem documentation on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem(v=vs.110).aspx) but failed to find any useful information.

Is there any way to get the content from the "txtContent" textbox from a TabItem ?

Comment: You can get this from the code behind `txtContent.Text` or use a MVVM and bind that content to a view model..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Grid grid = TheItem.Content as Grid;
TextBox txtContent = grid.Children[0] as TextBox;
string text = txtContent.Text;
```

Or simply:

```
TextBox txtContent = MainGrid.Children[0] as TextBox;
```